# BeanValidation not working for Radio Buttons

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, bean-validation, liferay-aui

I'm creating a portlet using SpringWebFlow, this portlet has a JSP having some entry fields, some dropdowns, and few radio buttons, I've used BeanValidation and annotations like @NotNull and @NotEmpty are working fine for dropdowns and entry fields, **but annotations are not working for RadioButton**, 
In my JSP i've this code

```
<aui:field-wrapper name="gender">
    <aui:input inlineLabel="right" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" label="male" checked="${surveyBean.gender == 'male' ? 'true' : 'false'}"/>
    <aui:input inlineLabel="right" name="gender" type="radio" value="female" label="female" checked="${surveyBean.gender == 'female' ? 'true' : 'false'}" />
</aui:field-wrapper>
```

In my PageBean I've the following code

```
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
public String getGender()
{
    return gender;
}
```

What I want is user should not left any fields blank or unselected, for entry fields and dropdown proper error messages are displayed from Validation.properties file if they are left blank,,, for radio button @NotNull and @NotEmpty are not working means they are not getting validated so even they are not selected user is able to go to next page...

Could any of you please guide me in the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

What is the value for gender which gets set for the backing bean. Bean Validation does not care from where it gets its data. It does not know anything about drop downs and radio buttons. The interesting things is what the different values are in your bean at the time validation is called. If there is no exception and not constraint violation, I would assume gender is neither null nor empty. It could for example be a whitespace. There is a difference between `@NotEmpty` and `NotBlank`. The latter does also check against whitespace characters.

Comment: I checked it, when radio button is not selected its value is set to **null**. I wrote a custom annotation to check its value where it shows the value is null and 'isValid' method returns false, problem seems to be MessageInterpolator where it somehow throws a null pointer exception... do you know if it could be because BeanValidation is not able to identify where to place the error message as radio buttons are two in number with same name and id? and probably that's the reason for this different behavior as other form fields are getting validated perfectly fine? Thanks

Comment: I think I've found the source of problem, posted a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831742/radio-button-field-not-found-in-portletrequest-getparametermap